# How to bind a function to angular directive which uses the link function to create the HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to bind a function to an angular directive. The HTML is created using the link function instead of using `template` or `templateUrl` properties of the directive. The problem is that functions can not be bound in the first case.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html ng-app="test">

<body>

  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <test-dir print="printValue(val)">

    </test-dir>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my script file:

```
// Code goes here

var testApp = angular.module('test', []);

testApp.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.printValue = function(val) {
    alert(val);
  }

})

testApp.directive('testDir', function() {
  return {

    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      print: '&' 
    } , 

    link : function(scope, element, attr){
      var template = "<button ng-click='print({val:\"Hello\"})'>Click</button>";
      element.append(template);
    }

  }

})
```

In this example the function `printValue` on the controller is not bound to the button.

I've created a plunker for the above example [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/tHR9Nqv3jH4pOjwKC6HK)

If I were to use the template property of the directive to create the HTML the same example works perfectly fine.

I've created another plunker for a functioning example using the template property [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/tPKhrHOEASbyreC17atY)

So, my question is how can I bind the function in the first example ? I have to create the HTML using the link function, because the HTML has to be created dynamically, this is just a simplification of the real problem.

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Change `restict` to `restrict`

Comment: thanks @A.Sharma I've edited the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `$compile` your html template.

Add this after your `element.append()` statement:

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

Here is a [working fork](https://plnkr.co/edit/aZBBodaQGZiydhaYMbGA?p=preview) of your plnkr.

For more details, check the documentation for [`$compile` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) in angular.